# OpenGL и Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl, gdi

Помогите, пожалуйста! У меня дома на старом компе стоит хр. Раньше писал на нём программы под OpenGL. Всё работало замечательно. Даже удавалось получать адреса функций (расширения OpenGL). При вызове функции `glGetString(GL_VERSION);` возвращалась строка "2.2.0". Шейдеры были доступны. Вообщем, всё было замечательно.

Купил ноут. Там винда 7. Видеокарта мощная. Все современные игры идут без проблем. Но вот беда. Мои программы не запускаются под ним. А именно, функция `glGetString(GL_VERSION);` возвращает строку "1.1.0". Из-за этого невозможно получить адреса новых функций. Никакие из расширений не работают. А кодить-то надо. Пробовал установить дрова на видюху - не помогло. Скачал прогу OpenGL extension viewer. Она мне пишет, что у меня 3 адаптера: gdi, и 2 мои видеокарточки (интегрированная и дискретная). Пишет, что на видеокартах есть полная поддержка OpenGL 3.0. А gdi рендер поддерживает только 1.1. Отсюда напрашивается вывод, что проблема не в ноуте, а в Windows 7, а именно: в инициализации. Как всё-таки настроить систему и как проинициализировать приложение, чтобы был доступен хардварный рендеринг посредством OpenGL 3.0, а не GDI'шный? Использую GLUT.

P.S. Игры на OpenGL тоже не работают. Space shuttle mission 2007 отказывается запускаться за неимением расширений.

P.P.S Может кто-нибудь знает, зачем нужен OpenGL ICD, и поможет ли его установка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я разобрался. Дело оказалось именно в дровах, но только там была очень большая заковырка. Т.к. на ноуте стоят радеон и интеловский чип, то я качал дрова с каждого сайта по отдельности. И что самое интересное, это не помогло. А проблема решилась, скачиванием дров с сайта производителя ноутбука. Они там особые, конкретно под каждую модель. После установки драйвера, графика работает под версией 3.0. Так что с ноутами свой разговор.

Answer (score 0):

1. Поставить XP
2. Отключить переключение видеокарт, думаю сходит с ума из-за него. Еще стоит поиграться с версиями драйверов.

Comment: С дровами пробовал. Переключение тоже не помогает. Проблема вся в том, что приложение нацелено на массового пользователя, и, поэтому, необходимо знать, как запустить его под вин 7 (линукс, хр и мак ось поддаются запуску без проблем). Очень нужно.